# Print Data from PLC to Python using pycomm

Tags: python, python-2.7, plc

I am trying to move data (a dint specifically but my example is a BOOL) from the plc to python to be used as a variable to display a picture. The issue is, if I use pycomm, I am getting an error in Windows Powershell. I feel this is a very simple error from a basic python mistake rather than a pycomm issue but I am not informed enough to tell.

SysInfo:

```
configparser==3.5.0  
cpppo==3.9.7  
greenery==2.1  
ipaddress==1.0.18  
pycomm==1.0.8  
pyreadline==2.1  
pytz==2017.2  
python==2.7.13
```

Code I am using:

```
from pycomm.ab_comm.clx import Driver as ClxDriver
import logging

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = ClxDriver()

    if c.open('IPADDRESSHERE'):

         print(c.read_tag(['new_Bool']))

         c.close()
```

Which is just a stripped down version of one of the examples on github  https://github.com/ruscito/pycomm

This is the result from running powershell:

> PS C:\Users\Tom\Documents\PythonProjects> python pycomm2.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "pycomm2.py", line 10, in 
>       print(c.read_tag(['new_Bool']))
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pycomm\ab_comm\clx.py", line 359, in read_tag
>       self.logger.warning(self._status)
>   AttributeError: 'Driver' object has no attribute 'logger'
>   PS C:\Users\Tom\Documents\PythonProjects>

I have looked for this AttributeError and tried to find a solution, but I think the solutions I have found are over my head. If I have failed to provide some details in order for this question to make sense please let me know.

Edit:

```
from pycomm.ab_comm.clx import Driver as ClxDriver
import logging


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(
        filename="ClxDriver.log",
        format="%(levelname)-10s %(asctime)s %(message)s",
        level=logging.DEBUG
    )
    c = ClxDriver()

    if c.open('IPADRESSHERE'):

        print(c.read_tag(['new_Bool']))


        c.close()
```

Yields the same attribute error.

> PS C:\Users\Tom\Documents\PythonProjects> python pycommtest.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "pycommtest.py", line 15, in 
>       print(c.read_tag(['new_Bool']))
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pycomm\ab_comm\clx.py", line 359, in read_tag
>       self.logger.warning(self._status)
>   AttributeError: 'Driver' object has no attribute 'logger'
>   PS C:\Users\Tom\Documents\PythonProjects>

Comment: I don't know my way around this specifically, but one of the bits you've stripped out of the example appears to be the logging setup.. the call to `logging.basicConfig(..`

Comment: I posted an update. I thought that might have been it as well so I used another example, but I must have done something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to read a value, but not with pycomm. Using CPPPO, I was able to continuously update a variable as needed. This may not answer the question of what was wrong with my old code, but it is my work around in case someone from the future has to do the same thing. Credit to user Liverpool_chris and the abyss of Reddit.

https://www.reddit.com/r/PLC/comments/5x3y5z/python_cpppo_library_writing_to_tag_in_plc/

```
from cpppo.server.enip.get_attribute import proxy_simple
import time

host = "IPHERE"
while True:
    x, = proxy_simple(host).read(( "CPID"))

    print x
time.sleep(5)
```